# In Meteor, how can I publish a single object from an array field?

Tags: meteor

I have the following Mongo collection:

```
{
 id: '123456',
 name: 'GameXYZ',
 reviews: [
   {createdBy: 'Bob', score: 5}, {createdBy: 'John', score: 8}
 ]
}
```

I would like to create a publish function that returns only the review created by Bob:

```
{
  reviews: [
   {createdBy: 'Bob', score: 5}
  ]
}
```

I've tried this:

```
return myCollection.find({'reviews.createdBy': 'Bob'}, {'reviews.$': 1});
```

The problem is Meteor returns the entire document. According to their documents, *"Field operators such as $ and $elemMatch are not available on the client side yet."*
My function is running on the server, so I don't know why it's not working. It **does** work on the Mongo Shell.

My question is: could anyone recommend a way to publish only that single object of the array, in Meteor?

Comment: try this `find({"reviews":{"$elemMatch":{"createdBy":"Bob"}}},{"reviews.$.createdBy":1})`

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work neither on the client nor server. It only appears to work on the Mongo Shell. I ended up taking Noah's suggestion and creating a reviews collection. Thanks anyway. Hopefully Meteor will support elemMatch soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done like the comments example from [discover meteor](https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/comments). Create new collection `reviews`. You can put what ever you need in it but it has to have the id of what ever it's a review of. That way you can publish and find it with `reviews.find({reviewsId: the id of the collection; in this case 123456})`

Comment: Thank you Noah. I've created the reviews collection and in it I'll add multiple documents, each has its "what it's for" field.